# Min Width Nested Table HTML Email

Tags: html, email, outlook

Code works fine in gmail and apples mail client but outlook is driving me crazy.

```
<table cellpadding="0" width="600" align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:10"            style="min-width:600px;">
<tr>
<td>    
<span style="font-family:Tahoma; background-color:#81DAF5; font-size:35px;"><i>Text</i>      </span>
</td>
<td>
<table align="right">
<tr>
<td align="right">
<span style="background-color:#ffffff; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva,   Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><i>Text</i></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">
<span style="background-color:#ffffff; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><i>Text</i></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want the entire table to have a min width of 600px but in outlook the text begins to wrap when I shrink the window size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a 'td' in a column (possibly in the 'thead' row but any 'tr' will work) and fill it with as many nbsp's as you need to maintain a minimum width. A nbsp is a non-breakable space, which means that (in most cases) will not be collapsed or allow a line wrap. A mono-spaced font works best for this.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <td style="font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MinimumWidthHolder&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>your text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

min-width [isn't supported](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) by Outlook.

You have a span and a table sitting within a table cell. Use different cells for each part. Something like this is a basic example:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <!-- Center Panel -->
      <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="400">
            <span style="font-family:Tahoma; background-color:#81DAF5; font-size:35px;">
              <i>Text</i>
            </span>
          </td>
          <td width="200" style="font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <!-- Nested to stack two rows, could also use br's or rowspans if preferred -->
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td align="right">
                  <i>Text</i>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">
                  <i>Text</i>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! Weird thing is I recreated the table you provided on top of my existing table but now both tables adhere to a min width of 600.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set a min-width for a table in HTML e-mail for Outlook, just make a tr and td with height 1 and width that is your desired min-width.

```
<!-- Outlook min-width hack -->
    <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="background-color: #FFFFF; padding: 0; margin:0;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="360" height="1" style="margin:0; padding: 0;">
                <tr style="margin:0; padding: 0;"><td height="1" width="360"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the inner table to 100%.

```
<table width="100%" align="right">
```

Answer (score 0):

What helped for me was to set the min-width (and max-width too, just to be sure) of both, the inner and outer table. Diodeus' suggestion of "100% on the inner table" didn't work for me at all.